# How to display grid lines in a flex 4 list?

Tags: list, apache-flex, flex4, flex-spark

I am newbie with Flex 4 (and Flex/AS in general).
I am using a spark list control to display certain items with my custom Item Renderer.
I am trying to achieve the following:
(1) show a separating line between rows in my list control
(2) even when not a single row has been added, I want a horizontal grid lines to be displayed in the background

I am not sure whether (1) and (2) can be achieved in one go.
I can solve (1) by modifying my item renderer to have a border, I guess. But I want to know whether there is a better or more conventional way.

I am not sure how to address (2).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like you said , drawing a line at the bottom of the item renderer.
As for (2), you could add a line directly on a custom list skin and remove it when the dataprovider is set

Comment: Hi, Thanks for you response. But I am not sure how the skin is going to work (referring to (2) ). The list initially must be blank and be the height of 10 rows. At this point I would want to see gridlines (9 separators). When the user adds an actual row, I should still be able to see the gridlines for the 9 blank rows (8 separators). Also the initial height (10 rows) might increase if the user resizes the window. If he drags and increases the size of the window my list might now be the height of 20 rows. Would your approach help with this too ?